# Improving MySQL I/O Performance (Hardware & Partitioning)

Tags: mysql, performance, io, amazon-ec2, hardware

I need to improve I/O performance for my database. I'm using the "2xlarge" HW described below & considering upgrading to the "4xlarge" HW (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Thanks for the help!

**Details:**

CPU usage is fine (usually under 30%), uptime load averages anywhere from 0.5 to 2.0 (but I believe I'm supposed to divide that by the number of CPU's) so that looks okay as well. However, the I/O is bad: iostat show favorable service times, but the time spent in queue (I suppose this means waiting to access the disk) is far too high. I've configured MySQL to flush to disk every 1sec instead of every write, which helps, but not enough. Profiling shows there are a handful of tables that are the culprits for most of the load (both read && write operations). Queries are already indexed & optimized, but not partitioned. Average MySQL states are: Sending Data @ 45%, statistics @ 20%, Updating @ 15%, Sorting result @ 8%.

**Questions:**

1. How much performance will I get by upgrading HW?
2. Same question, but if I partition the high-load tables?

**Machines:**

- m2.2xlarge

  - 64-bit
  - 4 vCPU
  - 13 ECU
  - 34.2 Gb Mem
  - EBS-Optimized
  - Network Performance: "Moderate"
- m2.4xlarge

  - 64-bit
  - 6 vCPU
  - 26 ECU
  - 68.4 Gb Mem
  - EBS-Optimized
  - Network Performance: "High"

Comment: For posterity, the config changes where critical. I also spent extra money on AWS Provisioned IOPS for the EBS volumes which was also key. At a later date I partitioned a couple big tables by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the biggest boost in MySQL performance comes from IO. You have alot of RAM. Try setting up a ram drive and point the tmpdir to it.

I have several MySQL servers that are very busy. My settings are below - maybe this can help you tweak your settings.

My Setup is:
-Dual 2.66 CPU 8 core box with a 6-drive Raid-1E array - 1.3TB. 
-innodblogs on a separate SSD drives.
-tmpdir is on a 2GB tempfs partition.
-32GB of ram

InnoDB settings:

```
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 22G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size = 400M
innodb_log_files_in_group=8
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 (This is a slave machine - 1 is not required fo my purposes) 
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

Current Queries per second avg: 5185.650

I am using Percona Server, which is quite a bit faster that other MySQLs from my testing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I mounted 2GB Ram disk & redirected temp table storage to it. After restarting mysql, it looks like I'm not using the 2GB though :( Do you happen to know any other config vars I need to change? Also, mind telling me what you've got for this? Thanks!

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%table_size'; -- shows 16MB for both max_heap_table_size & tmp_table_size

Comment: Update 10 years later b/c this post still gets views - this answer is solid. There is much to be gained by diving deeper into mysql performance tuning parameters that leverage memory to improve I/O, using design patterns that can be found in the Oreily high-performance mysql books &  http://mysql.rjweb.org/ by @rickames (batching/partitioning/sharding). Tuning your specific queries / table design / indexing /etc is of course profound & the first place I've learned to look when inheriting a system that wasn't initially engineered for performance at scale.